# How to create Iceberg table using Trino partitioned on a STRUCT/ROW column's inner field?

Tags: trino, apache-iceberg, data-lakehouse

I try creating the table with a partition on a field of a STRUCT/ROW type like so:

```
create table person(address ROW(city VARCHAR)) with (partitioning=ARRAY['address.city']);
```

I get this error:

```
Query failed: Unable to parse partitioning value: Invalid partition field declaration: address.city
```

Comment: Please check this issue - https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/8175